# Javascript: call a function inside a multiple instance variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code.

```
function coolStuff( name , options ) {
   this.name = name;
   this.options = options;
   this.children = $(name).children();


   this.children.each( function( index, value ) {
        //How can I call this.processMoreCoolStuff if im using multiple instance?

        this.processMoreCoolStuff( {} );
   });

   this.processMoreCoolStuff = function( param ) {
       //Some processing of this.options here!
   }

}


var coolStuffObj01 = new coolStuff( "#cs01", {} );
var coolStuffObj02 = new coolStuff( "#cs02", {} );
```

How can I call this.processMoreCoolStuff() if im using multiple instance? What is the best approach for this?

Comment: Inside the `each` callback function, `this` refers to the jQuery element not the `coolStuff` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `each` callback function, `this` refers to the jQuery element not the `coolStuff` function. You'll have to keep a reference to the `coolStuff` instance if you want to access it inside that callback.

Here is an example:

```js
function coolStuff( name , options ) {
   this.name = name;
   this.options = options;
   this.children = $(name).children();
   var self = this;

   this.processMoreCoolStuff = function( param ) {
       //Some processing of this.options here!
       console.log("@processMoreCoolStuff", param);
   }
   
   this.children.each( function( index, value ) {
        //How can I call this.processMoreCoolStuff if im using multiple instance?

        self.processMoreCoolStuff( {name:name, txt:$(value).text()} );
   });
}


var coolStuffObj01 = new coolStuff( "#cs01", {} );
var coolStuffObj02 = new coolStuff( "#cs02", {} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cs01">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
</div>
<div id="cs02">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. This is the fastest solution.. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do `coolStuffObj01.processMoreCoolStuff()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the function from each instance(object), in the function last use this `return this`. Then it will return an object.

Rewrite the function as

```
function coolStuff( name , options ) {
   this.name = name;
   this.options = options;
   this.children = $(name).children();


   this.children.each( function( index, value ) {
        //How can I call this.processMoreCoolStuff if im using multiple instance?

        this.processMoreCoolStuff( {} );
   });

   this.processMoreCoolStuff = function( param ) {
       //Some processing of this.options here!
   }
   return this; // this line is added

}
```

Now, if you want to access it, do the following

```
var coolStuffObj01 = new coolStuff( "#cs01", {} );
coolStuffObj01.processMoreCoolStuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure your code and use a constructor function & prototype.Using prototype only create only instance & will be shared.Functions created in the constructor are created as new objects for each new object created with the constructor.

```
function CoolStuff(name, options) {
  this.name = name;
  this.options = options;
  this.children = $(name).children();
}
CoolStuff.prototype.processMoreCoolStuff = function(param) {
  // rest of the code
}
CoolStuff.prototype.loopChild = function() {
  this.children.each(function(index, value) {
    this.processMoreCoolStuff(); 
  });
}



var coolStuffObj01 = new coolStuff("#cs01", {});
var coolStuffObj02 = new coolStuff("#cs02", {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.bind()` and just change the assignation order:

```js
function coolStuff(name, options) {
  this.name = name;
  this.options = options;
  this.children = $(name).children();
  this.processMoreCoolStuff = function(param) {}; // <----move it up here

  this.children.each(function(index, value) {
    this.processMoreCoolStuff({}); // 2. it knows where to find the method
  }.bind(this)); // <----1. when you bind "this"

}
```